# Allow Active Record Model to Assign Association using String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a fairly basic set of models where a 'Project' has one 'Owner'. I'd like to allow users to enter the owner's name when creating a new project. If owner doesn't exist, a new one should be created. Does a good way to do this exist? I've been thinking about using `attr_accessor` and `before_validation` however it seems it would conflict with the relationship. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something different than the name of your relationship... `owner_name` should be fine. Then write the necessary `before_validation` method.

Comment: Hi Fábio. Thanks for the answer. I ended up a minor tweak on this (found this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/57-create-model-through-text-field). My only question that remains is adding validations on the `attr_accessor` fields, but I'm sure I'll figure something out.

Comment: Nice, that Railscast can help a lot of people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something along the lines of this in your controller:

```
def update
  Project.transaction do
    @project.owner = Owner.find_or_create_by_name(params[:project].delete(:owner_name))
    @project.attributes = params[:project]
    @project.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy. This is fairly close to what I have currently. Just trying to figure out if a good way to 'DRY' up the code existed (had the same code for update and create, and in a few other spots around the application and felt like it should be into the model).

Comment: Alternatively you could define this in the model `def owner_name=(owner_name); owner = Owner.find_or_create_by_name(owner_name); end` then you would only need to use a form field with `project[owner_name]` and in any controller action, `update_attributes(params[:project])` should work a charm.